# How do I mask off stained wood without damaging the finish?

Tags: painting, hardwood-floor, stain

I'm trying to paint a surface that meets up at a slight angle with some stained wood edging that is part of my wood floor.

I started covering up the wood with blue painter's tape, and noticed when repositioning some tape that it was pulling bits of the wood surface off when I removed it. I checked the tape instructions and it turns out I'm not supposed to use it on wood floors, which is basically what this edging is.

So if I can't use painter's tape to protect the wood from the adjacent painting, how do I do the painting without accidentally painting the wood? Is there some other kind of special wood floor painter's tape I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a premium quality tape designed for delicate surfaces (example in pic, not a brand recommendation). Sometimes they are marketed as "easy release" or "gentle release".

[image]

Comment: You may need to visit an actual paint shop to find this, as opposed to a "big box" hardware store...